# When I restrict access to one folder it's affecting all the website .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have my .htaccess under the www folder on the server , this file contain some redirect rule nothing else.

Under the www folder , i have another folder www/admin and i want to restrict access to it  with .htpasswd file  and i have balanced this code into www/admin/.htaccess file :

```
  AuthName "Access denied"
  AuthUserFile /real_path_server/www/admin/.htpasswd
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
```

i tested everything work fine i can't access to /admin without login and password .

The problem so , that when i go to the website ,authentification window appear , everybody can see this window and this is'nt the behavior that i look for . 
i look for that authentification must be required if i want to access to websiteUrl/admin not when i want to access to websiteUrl.

```
      www
       |---admin
       |     |
       |     |----.htaccess (2)
       |     
       |
       |
       |.htaccess (1)
```

the code in .htaccess (1)

```
       SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       RewriteEngine on
       ErrorDocument 404 /erreur404.php
       RewriteRule *******************
       RewriteRule *******************
       RewriteRule *******************
```

And in the .htaccess2

```
          AuthName "Access denied"
          AuthUserFile /real_path_server/www/admin/.htpasswd
          AuthType Basic
          Require valid-user
```

Thanks for help

Comment: For testing rename `.htaccess (1)` to something else and then try in a new browser.

Comment: it affect all the website

Comment: Didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache .htaccess files "cascade". Which means all rules set by an .htaccess file in a parent directory will be applied to all sub-directories. You *cannot* remove a rule in a sub-directory by adding a .htaccess file without that rule, but you can overwrite it by adding that same rule with another value in a sub-directory's .htaccess file.

I'm certain there is another Apache configuration that you might not be able to see, or have access to. Are you using a shared web-hosting server? Is this your own local server? A VPS/Dedicated server where you have root access?

If you are on a shared server, I recommend calling their tech support as they would likely have intimate knowledge of their primary apache configurations.

Also just a quick tip. I noticed in your htaccess configurations above that you have your .htpasswd file in a publicly available directory. It is recommended that you put your .htpasswd files in a non public (non web-accessible) directory, and write the full path to the .htpasswd file in your .htaccess file.

Typically, this is not an issue and not necessary since most web-hosting service providers will add a rule in their "master" apache config file to not allow access (from the web) to any files that begin with .ht*. But not all of them do, so just be careful with that ;)

For example, using your current configuration, I might be able to type this directly in my address bar and see the contents of your .htpasswd file like this - http://your-site.com/admin/.htpasswd - if your web hosting service provider has not taken care of this contingency, it will literally spit out the contents of your .htpasswd file to my screen, where I can see the usernames available, and their obfuscated passwords. It's just a matter of security. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'am in a shared server . If i don't have answer from this post i'll call them thanks.

Comment: If it was your hosting provider that was the issue, please check back and mark this answer as correct for others who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default htaccess are folder based. Double check if there is a .htaccess into tje root of the webserver

Comment: Remove the (1) if not needed

Comment: thanks for answer but i can't because there is the rewrile rules and if i remove it i must change all urls in all php file .

Comment: RewriteRule CAN be the source of your problem, please at least post them.